# Python: A robust continuous loop with keyword keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, interrupt, keyboardinterrupt

Currently I have a program which follows:

```
    try:
    while True:
        print("Running")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

The idea bring that the terminal will print "Running" until the user inputs CRTL+C, what I want to be able to do is have the program continue to run until a user enters a key word in additional to this.  This is to make my program more robust so no accidental inputs could stop the loop.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a possible way to achieve that:

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Running")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if input("Type exit to exit: ") != "exit":
            continue
        break
```

Or if you want to a more flexible escaping string you can declare it as follow:

```
escape_string = "exit"

while True:
    try:
        print("Running")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if input(f"Type {escape_string} to exit: ") != escape_string:
            continue
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the try/except block to be *inside* the loop, so that the interrupt does not exit the loop. The exception handler activates the loop exit condition.

```
ans = ""
while ans != "please":
    try:
         print("Running")
         sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ans = input("Please enter secret ")
```